# Is there ample parking at the Staten Island Ferry?

Tags: public-transport, automobiles, new-york-city

I will be driving into New York City in the last week of July probably Friday the 28th.

I was considering parking my car for 4 days at a parking facility near the Staten Island ferry, and using the ferry to get in to Manhattan.

The ferry is a tourist thing to do, and I am all about tourist things, so I kind of get two birds with one stone, but I don't want to go all the way out to Staten island and not find parking.

Is there anyone who frequents these parking lots who could confirm if they commonly fill to capacity, or is it more common to find ample space?

Comment: I've done the ferry thing, but never left the terminal on Staten Island so don't know if there's parking. You could check Google StreetView, too. But even if there isn't long-term parking, there are many other options. You can easily find any parking lot and just take the subway, which goes right to the ferry. Something I've done in the past is park in Newark, NJ across from the PATH train station (I think it was around $20–40 a day), then take the train into New York right by the World Trade Center.

Comment: The answer would heavily depend on the time of the day and the day of the week.  And if you're taking public transportation to New York City it's better to take PATH into the city or even a Ferry if you so choose from Jersey City, Weehawken, Hoboken, etc.

Comment: @FighterJet Parking in Harrison and taking the path is better and parking could be cheaper on some of the older lots rather than in a garage.

Comment: @Karlson: It wasn't in a garage (can't fit a Chevy Express Extended van in there anyway), and it was with my family, so we had a lot of young children with us, with luggage. We did what was convenient.

Answer (score 1):

I used to park at the Staten Island Courthouse Garage and Parking Lot, perhaps two blocks from the ferry. It was $8 per day, but may have gone up in the past year or two (I usually take the train into NYC now). I usually had to climb a few levels, but I always found a spot.